# Assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I m getting the below error message while running the WebAPI service.

> 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Here are the version information

```
System.Web.Http 5.2.3
System.Web.Http.OData 5.5
System.Web.Http.WebHost 5.2.3
NewtonSoft.Json 6.0
```

Copy to Local set to True for all the Dll's. I tried to do update -package using Nuget and no go.

If i remove the OData reference, its working fine. 
I tried it in the other way by adding OData reference and including the namespace and simply commented the method where i used ODataQueryOptions, then it worked fine. Please help me with this and if any further information is required, i m happy to add it as well

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetEventStatusTypes   (ODataQueryOptions<UnAuthEventStatusType> options)
    {
        try
        {
            using (UnAuthAppAdminBusLib unAuthAppAdminBusLib = new   UnAuthAppAdminBusLib())
            {
                var eventStatusTypes =  unAuthAppAdminBusLib.GetEventStatusType(options) as  IEnumerable<UnAuthEventStatusType>;
                return  Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<UnAuthEventStatusType>> (HttpStatusCode.OK, eventStatusTypes);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should add a binding redirect for `System.Web.Http`.